# Consume from channel only if the number of messages reaches a count or the message is in the channel since a while

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I have a custom sink module and I would like to consume the messages from the `input` only if the the number of messages reaches a count or if they are in the channel since some time. In nutshell, I want to do a bulk push.

I have tried aggregating the number of messages after consuming and storing them in an aggregated channel backed by `SimpleMessageStore` and have `MessageGroupStoreReaper` checking for messages in the channel.

I am not satisfied with this approach as I am consuming the messages and storing them in an in-memory store, I am aware of the JDBC store as well but I don't want to follow this approach as the message channels in spring XD are backed by redis/mq I would like to consume from the `input` channel based on my conditions.

My current bean configuration is as shown below:

```
<int:aggregator id="messageAggregator" ref="messageAggregatorBean"
    method="aggregate" input-channel="input" output-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel"
    release-strategy="messageReleaseStrategyBean" release-strategy-method="canRelease"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" message-store="resultMessageStore">
</int:aggregator>

<int:service-activator id="contributionIndexerService"
    ref="contributionIndexerBean" method="bulkIndex" input-channel="aggregatorOutChannel" />

<bean id="resultMessageStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />

<bean id="resultMessageStoreReaper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="resultMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="60000" />
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="resultMessageStoreReaper" method="run"
        fixed-rate="10000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Any thoughts or comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you will be able to determine the count of messages in the Broker's queue (Redis/RabbitMQ or even just normal JMS), more over how much they have been there.

You definitely should *consume* them to do such a logic.

And yes, I think `Aggregator` can help you. But right: that must be a [Persistent Message Store](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-store).

for the case

> if they are in the channel since some time

The `Aggregator` suggest an option like `group-timeout` to *release* those groups which haven't reached the `releaseStrategy` condition, but you would like to emit them anyway over some time: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to